# Is it possible to dynamically create a Entity Framework Entity Data Model?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I would like to realize a dynamic query builder using ASPNET MVC; i will ask the user db parameters (hostname, db, user, passwd) and then would like to use Linq to query the database using Entity Framework. 
For doing this i need to create the Entity Data Model at runtime ... is it possibile a similar thing?

Comment: hmmm what is the desired effect, code-generation of the classes?

Comment: @Cris: how is it possible to create a EntityConnection based on the parameters without the CSL,SSDL & MSL in place.

Comment: I'm quite 'open minded' but it ain't clear how do you imagine to e.g. use LINQ if you don't have compiled entities. Apart from using 'dynamic linq'. You have an arbitrary db, right? and you'd like to pull that 'in' and into EDM, and use some EF 'flavor' (db, model, code first?)

Comment: Yes, i would like to compile entities at runtime ... is that impossible?

Comment: Cris, not impossible, just complex and you're sidelining the EF. Though interesting idea. You can compile but don't have those classes, you need reflection/interfaces. I think I Know what you need or some steps, possibilities (if you wanna go down that road) but not sure what you'd like as an answer, I can only give you some advises, ideas. And btw. you should use '@' to tag me here, I'm not being notified of it.

Comment: @NSGaga thanks for your reply. I would like to build a small query builder where the user can give a dbconnection, user and pass, then retrieving the tables and columns list can build its queries using a drag and drop interface. I know i can use ADO.NET but wanted to use something more modern ...

Comment: is this restricted for EDM approach ? What about code first ?

Comment: @Cris, can you give examples of what you want to achieve? inputs from view and resulting queries or entities

Comment: @soadyp i need database first approach; i would like to realize a query builder based on existing db tables.

Comment: This may be useful to you. Not EF but allows for zero config database first dynamic queries: http://keroseneorm.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 2):

I'm an EF fan but this just doesn't fit in IMHO!

I suggest that you just use ADO.NET instead of trying to use EF for your requirement.

However, if you're really against using ADO.NET then maybe one of the micro ORMs out there may be better (e.g. Dapper)